# What type of variable is this in php laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a food ordering web application and I am trying to deduct the total amount of an order from my wallet. The total amount is saved in the "payment.blade.php" page using the following variable.

Total Amount: @{{ withDelivery   }}

I have created a function, "pay_with_wallet($total)" in the Wallet controller that takes the total amount of the order as a parameter and returns a deducted amount from the wallet. But the total is not being passed to the function "pay_with_wallet($total)" from the "payment.blade.php" page.

[image: This is the payment.blade.php page where I am trying to pass the total in the function]

Can anybody tell me how to what type of variable  "@{{ withDelivery   }}" this is? And how can I pass it in a static function in my Wallet Controller?

Comment: Please share code in question - not an image.

Answer (score 0):

It is escaping the blade directive. The @ symbol will be removed by Blade; however, {{ withDelivery }} expression will remain untouched by the Blade engine, allowing it to be rendered by your JavaScript framework.

Take a look at official documentation: [Blade & JavaScript Frameworks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)

Comment: I am trying to send this variable value "withDelivery" which is in float type to my function "pay_with_wallet" in the controller. How do I do that? I tried the hidden input way but the variable is not passing though like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the @ symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched.

Blade:

```
<h1>Laravel</h1>
 
Hello, @{{ name }}.
```

Output:

## Laravel

Hello, {{ name }}.